# how to fix setting subsystem to console in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to pause console from exiting. so I'have set subsystem to console every time I make new project. I sick of this process. is there any way to fix subsystem to console when I make new project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. The only way to resolve this issue was to create a custom project template in Visual Studio. Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2017) on how to create a project template in Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio go to Project -> Project Properties -> scroll down to linker - > sysyem. in the right pane where it says SubSystem change that to Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)

Comment: I already know that. but I have to do that every time when I make a new project. so do you know how to set subsystem to console automatically when I make a new project?

Answer (score 0):

When you make projects, make an empty project. It is set to console by default.